# TensorFlow: 'module' object has no attribute 'SessionRunHook'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running TensorFlow version r0.10 on Ubuntu 16.04. I have been able to run some basic tutorials, including the MIST character recognition tutorial.

I'm trying to complete the [CIFAR-10](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#convolutional-neural-networks) tutorial example from TensorFlow, on tensorflow version r0.10.

When I execute *cifar10_train.py*

After:
*Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.*

The script fails with:

*File "cifar10_train.py", line 85, in train
    class _LoggerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SessionRunHook'*

Please could someone help me find the solution to this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are trying to run is from a later version of the TensorFlow repository than the  version you have installed:

- The code that uses `tf.train.SessionRunHook` was [added to the master branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/45009de073a203f54bff7cec0ea83f88c48237b9) on November 23rd, 2016, and is part of the r0.12 release.
- The `tf.train.SessionRunHook` class itself was [created on October 3rd, 2016](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commits/master/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py), and first became part of an official release in r0.12.

TensorFlow tutorial code only works with the contemporary version of the library. To run the CIFAR-10 tutorial using r0.10, you should clone the `r0.10` branch of the GitHub repository:

```
$ git clone -b r0.10 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem simply by uploading Tensorflow with `pip`.

`pip install -U tensorflow`