# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.estimator' has no attribute 'SessionRunHook'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorboard

I'm running TensorFlow version 1.9 on Ubuntu 18. I am trying to use tensorboard visualization .

I have installed tensorboard 1.9 with my anaconda prompt.
I have excuted this command :

**tensorboard --logdir=./eval/ --port=8090 --host=127.0.0.1**

eval is the file that contains summary data that i have generated when running TensorFlow .

The script fails with:

**File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_cpu/bin/tensorboard", line 7, in 
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 44, in 
    from tensorboard import default
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 36, in 
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder import beholder_plugin
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/__init__.py", line 15, in 
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder.beholder import Beholder
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/beholder.py", line 199, in 
    class BeholderHook(tf.estimator.SessionRunHook):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.estimator' has no attribute 'SessionRunHook'**

Please could someone help me find the solution to this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused due to 2 reasons:

1. inconsistency in versions between your Tensorflow and Tensosrboard.
2. if your tensorflow version is less than 1.10

Try to upgrade the versions of Tensorflow and Tensorboard so that the corresponding versions are greater than 1.12 and make sure the versions are consistent with each other. This should solve your problem.

For more information, you can refer to the following issues [[1]](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_18649781/article/details/89842430) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40869641/tensorflow-module-object-has-no-attribute-sessionrunhook)